# C# Character Incrementation

Tags: c#, increment

I'm new to C# so this question (hopefully) will be very simple.

I am trying to increment every character in a character array. This is my code.

```
        //increment each character in array
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            textArray[i]++; //this works
          // textArray[i] +=13; //this doesn't work 
        }
```

I am able to increment the array by one but not by more than that.

Thanks!

If it will help, here is the rest of my code.

```
        // put all text into a string - here loosely typed as a var
        var s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Eliezer Feder\Documents\2 Landers\Limudie Chol\5th Semester\C#\GettysburgAddress.txt");

        var upper = s.ToUpper();

        string text = ""; //empty string to add characters to it if they are indeed characters.
        foreach (char c in upper.ToCharArray())
        {
            if (Char.IsLetter(c))
            {
                text += c;
            }
        }

        //change the 'text' string to an array so can increment each individual char
        Char[] textArray = text.ToArray();

        //output old text in the char array:
        Console.WriteLine(textArray);
        Console.ReadKey();

        //increment each character in array
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            textArray[i]++; //this works
          // textArray[i] +=13; //this doesn't work 
        }

        Console.WriteLine(textArray);
        Console.ReadKey();

        //change back to string so can write to file:
        string lines = ""; //empty string to add characters to it if they are characters.
        foreach (char c in upper.ToCharArray())
        {
            lines += textArray[c];
        }


        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"Eliezer Feder\Documents\2 Landers\Limudie Chol\5th Semester\C#\encrypted.txt", lines); //THIS PART IS ALSO NOT WORKING FOR SOME REASON
```

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? do you get an exception? What is your expectation?

Comment: see http://www.dotnetperls.com/rot13

Comment: Always include full error messages (from exception or compiler) and google that first. The duplicate uses it in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of elements of `textArray` is `char`. Literal `13` is of type `int`. The result of adding `int` to `char` is `int`, so you cannot assign it to a `char` variable.

You have to cast the literal to `char`, then the result will also be a `char`:

```
textArray[i] += (char)13;
```